# Async logging is not reporting crashes

Tags: java, logging, quarkus, jboss-logging

I have a Quarkus application and enabled asynchronous logging:

```
quarkus.log.async=true
```

However, if there is a crash on startup which kills the process, the log is not output. This is quite an issue as the worse the problem the more likely I have no information to go on. Is there a way to somehow preserve the logs better? If I turn off async, the error is actually printed.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, can you please open an issue on GitHub?

Comment: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/20660
Filed here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed on quarkus as part of this issue in the library: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/20660